# Custom Polymorphic Types in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, polymorphic-relationship

I am working with polymorphic relationships and created a polymorphic tables with columns like

```
posts -:
   | id(integer) | title(string) | body(text) |

videos -: 
   | id(integer) | title(string) | url(text) |

comments -: 
   | id(integer) | title(string) | commentable_id(integer) | commentable_type(string) |
```

The default **commentable_type** would be either *App\Models\Post* or *App\Models\Video*, respectively.

I do not want to use these value for *commentable_type* want some **custom values**, found one approach with morphMap like -

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
    'posts' => 'App\Models\Post',
    'videos' => 'App\Models\Video',
]);
```

Looking for some other solution like some flag or method which can used in Model to achieve some results

Comment: why do you want custom values?

Comment: @AnuratChapanond my goal is Just to decouple the database from your application's internal structure

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/spatie/laravel-morph-map-generator